# Javascript closure object life

Tags: javascript, closures

This is code that creates a local object inside a closure.

```
function A() {
    this.welcome = "Welcome";
}

var P = (function() {
    var a = new A();
    function printa() {
        console.log(a);
    }
    return {
        printa: printa
    };
})();


P.printa();
```

It prints:

```
{ welcome: 'Welcome' }
```

After the P=... function is executed, P gets a new object that holds a reference to a function printa(), but at this time, local variable a should be freed. Why is it not freed?
Or is it temporarily there because it's not garbage collected?

Comment: My point is that although ``printa`` mentions ``a``, it is not executed at the time it's returned. So it make sense that ``printa`` should not keep the reference to ``a``, since it's a function, not a dictionary. Otherwise it needs to hold all the outside variables even is not executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is kept referenced by the closure from the `printa` function.

`a` will be garbage collected some time after there are no more references to the `printa` function.

Comment: Does that mean a function can actually holds all the variables mentioned inside it even without executing it? This makes a function more like an array or dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

There is the rule: if some variable is holding by some scope, than it is not free. In your example variable `a` is used by scope of `printa` function.

Answer (score 2):

`a` will always exist outside of that closure created by function `printa`. `a` is still within the scope chain of `printa`, so it is not freed (i.e., garbage collected) until there are no more references to `printa`

However garbage collection varies from browser to browser (IE6 anyone?), so all bets off on exactly when it will exactly be garbage collected.